# Pass parameters throught struts.xml

Tags: java, xml, exception, redirect, struts2

I have 2 applications. One is PurchaseProj and another PayProj. From PurchaseProj i want to pass parameter to PayProj. I am reffering [This](http://ihatebugs.net/2013/09/how-to-pass-parameters-in-struts-xml/) Page for my solution.

Now following is code I have done.

```
sessionMap.put("Param1", requestparam);
```

This i wrote in action class of PurchaseProj. I am putting value in session. Further, in struts.xml,

```
    <action name="DB" class="com.Aditya.payAction">
        <result name="SUCCESS" type="redirect">
            <param name="Param1">${Param1}</param>
            <param name="location">http://localhost:8081/PayProj/LandingPage.jsp</param></result>
        <result name="ERROR">welcome.jsp</result>
    </action>
```

I am passing this session value and redirecting to PayProj. In PayProj, I am accessing this value through .jsp page,

```
<%String receiveParam=request.getParameter("Param1");%>
<%=receiveParam%>
```

But i am getting following error,

```
Dec 8, 2014 12:05:16 PM com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.OgnlUtil internalSetProperty
WARNING: Caught OgnlException while setting property 'Param1' on type 'org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ServletRedirectResult'.
ognl.NoSuchPropertyException: org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ServletRedirectResult.Param1
at ognl.ObjectPropertyAccessor.setProperty(ObjectPropertyAccessor.java:132)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.OgnlValueStack$ObjectAccessor.setProperty(OgnlValueStack.java:68)
at ognl.OgnlRuntime.setProperty(OgnlRuntime.java:1656)
at ognl.ASTProperty.setValueBody(ASTProperty.java:101)
at ognl.SimpleNode.evaluateSetValueBody(SimpleNode.java:177)
at ognl.SimpleNode.setValue(SimpleNode.java:246)
at ognl.Ognl.setValue(Ognl.java:476)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.OgnlUtil.setValue(OgnlUtil.java:186)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.OgnlUtil.internalSetProperty(OgnlUtil.java:360)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.OgnlUtil.setProperties(OgnlUtil.java:76)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.OgnlUtil.setProperties(OgnlUtil.java:49)
at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsObjectFactory.buildResult(StrutsObjectFactory.java:95)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.createResult(DefaultActionInvocation.java:195)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.executeResult(DefaultActionInvocation.java:342)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:253)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:221)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:86)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:150)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:48)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:86)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:123)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:167)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:86)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:105)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:83)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:207)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:74)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:127)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ProfilingActivationInterceptor.intercept(ProfilingActivationInterceptor.java:107)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:206)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:115)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:143)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:121)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:86)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:170)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:123)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:176)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:50)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:504)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.doFilter(FilterDispatcher.java:419)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:286)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:845)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Dec 8, 2014 12:05:20 PM com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ActionValidatorManagerFactory <clinit>
```

Please advice me. I am newbie to struts.

Comment: what is the version of struts?.

Comment: @Vishnu, I am using struts2. Do you have any suggestions? Its very urgent to me.

Comment: If your projects are running on 2 different struts.xml, then there is no standard way of passing apart from query string.

Comment: Can you point me to some web page where I can find how to pass parameters using querystring? My project runs on two different struts.xml.

Comment: I would suggest the following: 1) As you are calling the action of another project, dynamically construct the query parameters by appending them as a key-value pair. 2) If solution 1 is not possible then keep the value of interest in a higher scope (application) and reset that when you have used the value.

Comment: Even if i put parameter in application scope. When i redirect to different web application, will that parameter be available in second web app also? Are you sure with this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66382/discussion-between-aditya-ekbote-and-vishnu).